# Trying to pull external links from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out the best way extract links from an array in JavaScript. I want the user to be able to click the "Try Me" button and have that function loop through until it hits the links for the external sites that I want to connect my portfolio projects to.

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3rjF.png)

I've tried using `a` tags as well as declaring it as its own new thing but I cant seem to get it to work. Here is an example:

```
const Portfolio = () => {
    const  portfolios = [
      {
        id: 1,
        src: Apsnip,
        path: 'https://rapidapi.com/ChristopherTheDevCo/api/crpytonux/',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        src: Hdysnip,
        path: 'https://rapidapi.com/ChristopherTheDevCo/api/crpytonux/'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        src: Hhsnip,
        path: 'https://rapidapi.com/ChristopherTheDevCo/api/crpytonux/'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        src: Rsnip,
        path: 'https://rapidapi.com/ChristopherTheDevCo/api/crpytonux/'
      },
    ]
  return (
    <div name='portfolio' className=' bg-gradient-to-b from-black to bg-purple-950 w-full text-white md:h-screen'>
      <div className='max-w-screen-lg p-4 mx-auto flex-flex-col justify-center w-full h-full'>
        <div className='pb-8'>
          <p className='text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-gray-500'>Some Creations</p>
          <p className='py-6'>These are some of my projects. You can review them here.</p>
        </div>
            <div className='grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-8 px-12 sm:px-0'>
            {
            portfolios.map(({id, src, path}) => (
              <div key={id} className='shadow-md shadow-gray-600 rounded-lg'>
                
              <img src={src} alt="" className='rounded-md duration-200 hover:scale-105'/>
               <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
               <button className='w-1/2 px-6 py-3 m-4 duration-200 hover:scale-105'>Try Me</button>
                </div> 
              </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code into the question directly, preferrably as a [mcve]. That way others can read the code better and get enough context necessary to answer your question. Also please explain what "doesn't work" and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @LW001 new to this, so I should literally copy/paste a piece of my code here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) explains more why you shouldn't use images of code

Comment: Yes, copy-paste enough code so someone can better reproduce and understand the problem you're seeing. The link from my earlier comment sums up the best practices for this.

Comment: thank you i will read over it now. should I post this as a new question following this method or is there a way to edit this existing one?

Comment: There's an edit button below every question

Comment: @MushyAvocado thank you, i panicked and blindly looked right past it. much appreciated.